# Can't upgrade from Ubuntu Mate 19.10 to 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, mate, 20.04

I am having troubles to upgrade to Ubuntu mate 20.04 from 19.10 I get the following errors:

```
Atingido:1 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Atingido:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                                                   
Atingido:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease                                                           
Atingido:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease                                        
Atingido:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                   
Atingido:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease                      
Atingido:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
A ler as listas de pacotes... Pronto
A construir árvore de dependências       
A ler a informação de estado... Pronto
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
gsl@GSLHP-Pavilion-g6:~$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Pronto
brltty/eoan 5.6-11ubuntu2 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.5-4ubuntu2.0.1]
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
gsl@GSLHP-Pavilion-g6:~$
```

can someone give me a hand with this please.

Thank you
GSL

Comment: Error messages in portugese are not very helpful (except for Portugese, of course, but that's not the purpose of StackOverflow EN).

Answer (score 1):

Start with installing all updates to the current system by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then start upgrade to 20.04 LTS with

```
update-manager -c -d
```

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try it :).

Comment: Why does it still require -d option, if it was released several days ago already?

Comment: The `-d` is needed until release of 20.04.1. This is a bit stability-security measure.